# Typo in SOAP WebServExp.GenerateXMLSchema?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2007

We've recently setup out own webservice using SOAP and it all works like a charm.
Because the service is only used from within our own applications, I usually don't allow for a WSDL to be generated.

Today i started some tests with SoapUI and needed a WSDL of our own service. So I enabled the Default action of the TWSDLHTMLPublish component and tried to get the WSDL exported. All I got was an access violaton in WebServExp.GenerateXMLSchema, line 1636:

```
if (ParentInfo = nil) and ((GetTypeData(ATypeInfo).ParentInfo)^ <> nil) then
```

Debugging this, reveiled that `GetTypeData(ATypeInfo).ParentInfo`returned a nil, so of course using ^ on nil raises an access violation.

After removing the carret i had no problems generating the WSDL.

So did I find myself a bug here or am I missing something?

BTW: We have created our own SOAP.bpl, containing all original Delphi soap sources, to correct it for a known problem with exception derived from TRemotableException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So did I find myself a bug here or am I missing something?

Yes, that's a bug. And Subversion reveals it's been like that for many years - for as long as we've been on Subversion:(. [I am not setup to access the previous Starteam repository anymore].

I'm making to a note to remedy and check in unit tests for this. Please feel free to file a QC if time allows. And I'd like to hear more about the issue with TRemotableException-derived types.

Cheers,

Bruneau

Comment: The TRemotableException problem can be found way back , and there is a QC about it (#57210), which states it is solved ... but several resources keep reporting it. See a post of DrBob referencing a fix: http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinA2.htm

Comment: Hello,

The item mentioned in QC #57210 was remedied and I see that a unit test (that runs with every checkin) was added. Other tests were later added to cover other variations. If you're still running into an issue there, do send me (or post via QC) some information: namely the binding generated for the custom fault type and the XML packet that's not being properly deserialized: I'll make sure it's remedied and add another testcase.

Thank you for the QC about WebServExp.pas: I've promoted and will check in a fix and unit test soon.

Cheers,

Bruneau